# How build array in javascript and receive it in c# mvc controller

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc

It's possible to build an array in jquery/javascript to send it to my controller c# ?

I get a list of employes from a select multiple, i can alert them like this :

```
    <div class="demo">
        <select style="display:none" id="liste" multiple="" placeholder="Select">
            @foreach (var employe in ViewBag.Employes)
            {
            <option value="@employe.ID_Employe">@employe.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>

    <a class="btn btn-default" id="check" href="#">Suivant</a>
```

My script :

```
        $('#check').on('click', function () {
            $("#liste").find("option:selected").each(function () { alert($(this).text()); });
        });
```

I send data like this :

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/MyAjaxRoute',
            data: { arraytosend: arraybuildInJS },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    alert('yes');
                }
        },
```

- Can you explain me how to make an array in js and to receive it in a c# mvc controller ?

Comment: where is your controller code?

Comment: i dont code the controller code actually

Comment: use this var ajaxResult=[];

Comment: use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38041679/how-to-pass-array-to-mvc-controller-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create an Action in your Controller as:

```
public JsonResult SaveArrayData(List<string> myData)
{
   if(myData.Count == 0) return Json(new {success = false});

   //do something with myData
   return Json(new {success = true});
}
```

Then in your js code you can do the following:

```
var array = [];
$('#check').on('click', function () {

$("#liste").find("option:selected").each(function () {
    array.push($(this).text)
});

$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     url: '@Url.Action("SaveArrayData", "MyController")',
     data: { myData: array },
     success: function (response) {
       if (response.success) {
          array = [];//empty the array you can also use array.length = 0
          alert('yes');
       }          
     }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess [push](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) is what you're looking for.

```
var arraybuildInJS = [];
$('#check').on('click', function () {
            $("#liste").find("option:selected").each(function () { arraybuildInJS.push($(this).text()); });
        });
```

Remember you should expect an Enumerable of string in your controller. As you don't code it, try matching the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Thx your for your answers, i can succesfull send my data but i dont find the way to  parse it in my c# controller

```
public ActionResult GetAjaxSession(string searchequipe)
    {
        if (searchequipe != null)
        {
            var equipe_decode = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(searchequipe);

// how to parse my json variable : searchequipe ? 

            return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return null;


    }
```